# Mysql The results of the query

Tags: php, html, mysql

my mysql query results examples are here ;

```
    id = 45
species = Felis
generic = Leo
labidenlabel = S131
accessnumber = 4545
specimen = Blood
storedas = DNA
storedat = aDNA
storin = Beko Refrigerator
```

And I want to see them like ;

```
        id = 45
species Name = Felis
generic Name = Leo
labiden Label = S131
Access number = 4545
specimen = Blood
stored As = DNA
stored At = aDNA
store In = Beko Refrigerator
```

etc.

And there is my php code , I want to change result area. Not mysql field , Need to see specific name.

Sory for my bad English...

```
   <?php
     error_reporting(1);
    $speci1=$_GET['id'];

    $baglan=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$baglan){
     die('Bağlantı Hatası:' . mysql_error()); 
    }
    $sec=mysql_select_db("test",$baglan);

    $sql= "SELECT * from bilgiler where id='$speci1'";


    $sorgu=mysql_query($sql,$baglan);
    if(mysql_num_rows($sorgu) > 0){
            $satir=mysql_fetch_assoc($sorgu);

            foreach ($satir as $key => &$value) {

                    echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
            }
    }else{
        echo "Kayıt Bulunamadı!";
    }
    ?>
```

how can I change  result page?
Thank you .

Comment: You should not be using the mysql methods as they have been depreciated. Please look into using mysqli or PDO as alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

use mysql [alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). instead of

```
select * from
```

use

```
select id, species as 'species Name', ... from
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define in your select statement how the result set will look like - including changing names for columns

for example

`SELECT accessnumber AS 'Access number', labidenlabel AS 'labiden Label'  from bilgiler where id='$speci1`'

Will return a result set:

> Access number = 4545 
>   labiden Label = S131

This can be done specifically for all of the columns you need.